# PHP echo value of a object from array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have a array which I am printing using print_r.

```
<?php
print_r ($this)
?>
```

I get following result in my browser.

```
PackingListForm Object
(
    [objShipment:protected] => Shipment Object
        (
            [objCustomFieldArray] => 
            [intShipmentId:protected] => 38
            [strShipmentNumber:protected] => 1035
            [intTransactionId:protected] => 97
            [intFromCompanyId:protected] => 1
            [intFromContactId:protected] => 1
            [intFromAddressId:protected] => 1
            [intToCompanyId:protected] => 2
            [intToContactId:protected] => 3
            [intToAddressId:protected] => 2
            [intCourierId:protected] => 1
            [strTrackingNumber:protected] => 
            [dttShipDate:protected] => QDateTime Object
         )
)
```

Now I want to print / echo intTransactionId.

I have used following variable to echo the result, but I am getting undefined variable.

```
<?php
$noted = $this->objShipment->intTransactionId;
print_r ($noted);
?>
```

I am getting following php exception error in my browser.

Undefined GET property or variable in 'Shipment' class: intTransactionId
Line 33:    $noted = $this->objShipment->intTransactionId;

My question is how can I echo / print value of intTransactionId?

Comment: The intTransactionId property has `protected` visibility. Are you sure that `Shipment` doesn't have an API with which you can get that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`intTransactionId` is a protected property which means that you can't access it outside of the class itself (or parennt class or child class).

The exception, I think, is thrown in a `__get` magic method defined in `Shipment` (or one of its parent classes). This method is called when trying to access an unset property (or non-accesible property).

Please check this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

First try to convert it into array and then it will be much easier :),

```
$newArray = (array)$this;
print_r($newArray);//to see what can you get from there

// get_object_vars
$newArray = get_object_vars($object);
```

The object is from class PackingListForm, have look on that class if you have access and see if there is any get() function.